# Can anyone identify this uniform for me please? He was a marksman and back of photo says trophies won in war

Tags: military, identification, uniform

[image]

He was a military man who has marksman insignia on his uniform. The photo says trophies won in war and he was Irish.

Comment: Can you supply a pic of the back?

Comment: It seems he is wearing a "Musketry best shot skill-at-arms" badge. (I cannot tell if the blob above the crossed rifles is a crown, as illustrated at http://www.uniformology.com/HEAVY-CAV-08.html, or a star, as illustrated at (say) https://milart.blog/2016/08/30/marksmanship-badges-of-the-canadian-militia/.)

Comment: Do you have an approximate date (even the decade) of the photo, and/or an idea of which war(s) he might have participated in?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no date or decade but some I've spoken to think maybe the Boer Wars of earlier. The person we think it may be was born in early 1800s.